# In standard SQL, how do I select rows such that for each unique value in one column, all of the values in another column are a specified value?

Tags: sql

In standard SQL, how do I select rows such that for each unique value in one column, all of the values in another column are a specified value?

For example, in the table below, I want to select all values of column c_1 where the value of c_s is 'd' for each distinct value of c_1. So for c_1 = '2', all values of c_s are 'd'. Same for c_1 = '3'. This is not, however, the case for c_1 = '1', '4', or '5'.

Here is my table:

```
 id | c_1 | c_2 | c_s
----+------+---------+--------
 1  | 1    | 1       | d
 2  | 1    | 2       |
 3  | 2    | 1       | d
 4  | 2    | 2       | d
 5  | 2    | 3       | d
 6  | 3    | 1       | d
 7  | 4    | 1       | r
 8  | 5    | 1       | d
 9  | 5    | 2       | r
```

Here is what I would like to return from my sql query:

```
 c_1 | c_2 | c_s
----+---+--------
 2    | 1       | d
 3    | 1       | d
```

(I'm not sure how to phrase this question - key words, etc. - so please excuse me if there is better phrasing that would lead to a solution that is already posted here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT c_1
     , MIN(c_2) AS c_2
     , MAX(c_s) AS c_s
FROM Table1
GROUP BY c_1
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN c_s = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      + MAX(CASE WHEN c_s = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ca76/9)

In your example output you chose `1` for `c_2` even though other values exist, so I used `MIN()`, but if you wanted a different value to be chosen that logic could be adjusted.

Comment: Or just make that having clause read: `HAVING MIN(c_s) = MAX(c_s) and c_s = 'd'`

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out. Here is what I used `WITH newtable AS (SELECT c_1, COUNT(DISTINCT(c_s)) AS cds, COUNT(c_s) as cs, MIN(c_s) as fs FROM test1 GROUP BY c_1 ORDER BY c_1) SELECT * FROM newtable WHERE cds=1 AND fs='d'`. Your solution also works, so I am accepting yours.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Depends on if the missing value is `NULL` or just blank, `NULL` gets ignored by aggregates and causes that logic to fail, but if it's blank that'd work, though you'd need the last one to be `MAX(c_s) = 'd'` instead of just `c_s = 'd'` since it's in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to goat CO's. I check the count for each value and compare it to the number of D's.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdfd7/1)**

```
select 
  c_1      as 'c_1',
  min(c_2) as 'c_2',
  min(c_s) as 'c_s'
from yourTable
group by c_1
having count(1) = sum(case when c_s = 'd' then 1 else 0 end)
```